# Python - Calling a function from a different class to draw a line using PyQt Error: "'sip.wrappertype'"

Tags: python, class, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create two classes using PyQt to create a gui like so;

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint

class line():
    def makeline():
        qp.drawLine(250,250,350,300)

test = line()

class ShapeDrawer(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)
    self.show()
  def paintEvent(self, event):
    qp = QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)
    line.makeline()
    qp.end()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = ShapeDrawer()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However when I run this code, I recieve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ShapeDrawer.py", line 25, in paintEvent
    line.makeline()
  File ".\ShapeDrawer.py", line 9, in makeline
    qp.drawLine(250,250,350,300)
NameError: name 'qp' is not defined
```

And when I try to define QPainter within the function like this;

```
class line():
    def makeline():
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(ShapeDrawer)
        qp.drawLine(250,250,350,300)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ShapeDrawer.py", line 27, in paintEvent
    line.makeline()
  File ".\ShapeDrawer.py", line 10, in makeline
    qp.begin(ShapeDrawer)
TypeError: begin(self, QPaintDevice): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit: 
Additionally I received the advice `when you define the draw method, you could add an additional argument which is a QPainter object, and when you call this method in paintEvent, you could pass the qp defined in that method as an input.` However I am unsure of how to implement this myself and would also appreciate help doing this as well!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `qp` does not exists in the scope of `makeline`.

Creating a new one like you did won't help for two reasons:

- you are trying to paint on a class, but QPainter can only be initiated on an *instance*;
- painting has to operate on a QPainter instance created in the `paintEvent` and *on* the widget, and starting a painter on a widget can *only* happen within a paintEvent;

Just add the painter as parameter to the `makeline` function, then call it with the painter argument.

```
class line():
    def makeline(qp):
        qp.drawLine(250,250,350,300)


class ShapeDrawer(QWidget):
    # ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
      qp = QPainter()
      qp.begin(self)
      line.makeline(qp)
      qp.end()
```

Note that defining a new class that only does what you are showing is almost useless, unless you want to use a common object that retains a "collection" of functions, so you could just put the function in the main indentation.

Also, even in the case of using that class as a "collection", what you're doing is technically a static method (but you didn't make it like that); if you try to create an instance you won't be able to call it. Let's test it, using `makeline` on the `test` instance:

```
test = line()
# ...
class ShapeDrawer(QWidget):
    # ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
      qp = QPainter()
      qp.begin(self)
      test.makeline(qp)
```

This will result in the following error:

```
TypeError: makeline() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

And that's because an instance method always has the class instance (what's generally called "self") as its first argument.
So, you either add the static method decorator:

```
class line():
    @staticmethod
    def makeline(qp):
        qp.drawLine(250,250,350,300)
```

or you add `self` to it:

```
class line():
    def makeline(self, qp):
        qp.drawLine(250,250,350,300)
```

Also remember that is common (and highly suggested) convention to use capitalized names for classes and lower case names for functions and variables only (read more about it in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), aka PEP 8).

Finally, note that you can instantiate a QPainter directly with the object on which the painting will happen as first argument, and if you're using the painter in a paintEvent it's not required to end it, as that will happen automatically as soon as the paintEvent returns:

```
    def paintEvent(self, event):
      qp = QPainter(self)
      line.makeline(qp)
```